# net core start process on Unix

Tags: .net-core

I have a net core application.
I'm trying to start process on unix (raspbian)

```
           new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("~/Deploy/PROTOTYPE/Launcher/Launcher")
                {
                    Arguments = "",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            }.Start();
```

and catch exception:

> No such file or directory

but executable '~/Deploy/PROTOTYPE/Launcher/Launcher' exists and works fine via bash.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot use relative paths when having `UseShellExecute` set to `False` IIRC

Comment: Thanks. Absolute path solve my problem!